# linux ext4 file system I/O completion waiting routine?

Tags: linux, io, ext4

Currently I'm digging into I/O stack of linux kernel (v4.14), especially for block devices.

Whenever an I/O request is happened through VFS, and the request goes through ext4 file system, how can ext4 can be noticed when the requested i/o is completed?
Where should I look for the i/o completion handling policy?

I followed to the point inside the function ext4_mpage_readpages() inside ext4/readpage.c, but cannot go further...

It seems for the case of direct IO, waiting routine for direct I/O is obvious to find (dio_await_completion), but hard to figure out for the case of buffered IO. Maybe my understanding in direct / buffered IO is not adequate.

I'm very new to linux kernel, so I appreciate any advice!

Comment: bi_end_io holds the address of the callback function in the bio.

Comment: @stark Thx, I got the point!